# How to change color of a button fast

Tags: button, kivy, kivy-language

I'm Building a quiz app, I want after the user answer the question that the right answear will become green and the other to red and return to normal afterwards

I tried to use the Time.sleep() method but only made a dealy and the GUI didnt change at all

```py
     def send_answer(self, text):
     return self.success() if text == self.correct else self.end_game()
```

```py
def get_new_question(self):
        rnd_sql = "SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;"
        four_persons = GAME_DB.execute(rnd_sql, ())
        four_persons_names = [" ".join([person[0], person[1]]) for person in four_persons]
        self.answers = four_persons_names
        rnd_num = random.randrange(0, 4)
        self.correct = four_persons_names[rnd_num]
        print four_persons_names[rnd_num]
        self.pic = CoreImage(io.BytesIO(four_persons[rnd_num][2]), ext=four_persons[rnd_num][3])
        self.ids.main_pic.texture = self.pic.texture
        buttons = ["button_{0}".format(i + 1) for i in range(0, 4)]
        for b in buttons:
            # Return to normal color
            self.ids[b].background_color = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
```

```py
    def success(self):
        self.score += 10
        buttons = ["button_{0}".format(i + 1) for i in range(0, 4)]
        for b in buttons:
            if self.ids[b].text == self.correct:
                #Change to Green
                self.ids[b].background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]
            else:
                #Change to Red
                self.ids[b].background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
        self.get_new_question()
```

i expected that the color will be changed to Red/Green for a small time and then return to normal and so on

Comment: So what exactly happens (what does `didn't succseed` mean)?

Comment: @JohnAnderson i though of using the sleep method but it only "stopped time" and continue like always (didnt change the color at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `success()` method changes the `background_color`, then calls `get_new_question()`, which changes `background_color`  back to normal. Typically, when a series of changes to a GUI element is made in rapid succession, only the last one will appear, so in this case you will see no change. Also, calling `Time.sleep()` on the main thread will just cause a delay, but will not allow the color change to be displayed.

I would suggest changing your call to `self.get_new_question()` with something like

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.get_new_question, 0.5)
```

This will delay the call to `self.get_new_question()` by half a second, so you should see the color change. You will also need to change the signature of `self.get_new_question()` to

```
def get_new_question(self, dt):
```

or

```
def get_new_question(self, *args):
```

Comment: Sorry I am quite new